# How I can put two webview (one above another webview)

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

I'm trying to do a layout with two webviews. My problems is when I want putting  one above another webview. They are put in different positions. Thank's you!! ;)

I write here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >


     <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webview2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:autoLink="web"
         android:scrollbars="none"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="570dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why do u need webviews one over another?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>


     <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webview2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:autoLink="web"
         android:scrollbars="none"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="570dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this depends on whether you are trying to stack them, so that one is physically over the top of the other, i.e. covering it up, or whether you're asking to be able to stack them both on the screen so that one is at the top, and the other is below it, towards the bottom.

if that's the case, i'd suggest you place them in a RelativeLayout, and use a combination of android:layout_align.... and android:layout_above|below properties to get them lined up.

you can then switch them around by changing the layout_above|below attributes e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >


 <WebView
     android:id="@+id/webview2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:autoLink="web"
     android:scrollbars="none"
     android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="570dp"
android:autoLink="web"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
android:layout_below="@id/webview2"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank's rspython. Your answer is very good too! ;) I go to try! ;)

Comment: don't forget to accept whichever answer correctly solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try putting both the webviews in a framelayout. That will stack the views.